# How to get uppercase hex in printf()

Tags: c, printf, uppercase

I am experimenting with the following code. It outputs a in hex, sa in decimal.
I cant figure out how to “Upper Case” the value for a as “F”.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

Void foo()
{
    int a = 10;
    static int sa = 10;
    a += 5;
    sa += 5;
    printf("a = %x, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        foo();
}
```

Comment: Use `%X` for Uppercase letters in Hex.

Comment: See the man page on almost any system, or [the more granular GNU 'info'](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Table-of-Output-Conversions.html)

Comment: You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and please read "[ask]". You are supposed to do a good part of own research. Please [edit] your question and add what you did, what you found, and why it does not help you. You did read the documentation of `printf()`, didn't you?

Answer (score 3):

To convert integers to hexadecimal format in uppercase, use `%X`. Note that the `0x` prefix output for non zero values for `%#x` will also be uppercased with `%#X`

Similarly, you can use `%E`, `%F`, `%G` and `%A` to convert floating point numbers using uppercase letters instead of lowercase.

C23 added binary conversion with `%b`, and if used with the `#` modifier `printf` outputs a `0b` prefix for non zero values. `%#B` can be used to produce a `0B` prefix instead.

Comment: My favorite is to use lower case prefix and upper case digits: `printf("a = 0x%X, sa = %d\n", a, sa);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: This is my preference too.